# MySQL - Optimize select with join to a large table

Tags: mysql, query-performance, optimization

I have done some digging and found exactly no help at all for questions similar to this one. Basically I have two tables where one stores user posts and the other holds the moderation of the records of in table a "marketplace".

Table schema A(marketplace)

```
-- has 15 million records
create table marketPlace(
    ID          bigint auto_increment primary key,
    USER_ID     bigint                            not null,
    TITLE       varchar(60)                       not null,
    DESCRIPTION varchar(1000) collate utf8mb4_bin not null,
    COUNTRY     varchar(2)                        not null comment 'Country iso_code.',
    VIEWS       bigint default 0                  not null,
    DATE        bigint                            not null
);
create index COUNTRY on marketPlace (COUNTRY);
create index DATE on marketPlace (DATE);
create index ID_and_country_index on marketPlace (ID, COUNTRY);
```

Table schema B(moderation)

```
-- also has 15 million records
create table moderation(
    ID          bigint auto_increment primary key,
    adID        bigint not null comment 'The ID of the post being flagged',
    mode_flags  json   not null comment 'Flags added by approved moderators',
    flag_status bigint as (json_unquote(json_extract(`mode_flags`, '$.mod.flag'))) stored comment 'Post moderation status',
    date        bigint not null
);
create index composite_index on moderation (adID, flag_status);
create index flag_status on moderation (flag_status);
create index modID on moderation (modID);
```

And am using the following select with join query that's taking almost 2 minutes.

```
SELECT
    market_place.COUNTRY
    ,moderation.flag_status

FROM marketPlace market_place
    #use index (COUNTRY)

     INNER JOIN (
        SELECT adID, flag_status
        FROM moderation #use INDEX(composite_index)
    )moderation ON(moderation.flag_status = 1 AND market_place.ID = moderation.adID)
WHERE market_place.COUNTRY='GB'
LIMIT 25;
```

As you can see in the query above, I have also tried to force MySQL to use indexes and I still get results after 120 seconds or so. I did run a quick `explain` on the query and showed that indexes are being used but somehow still takes way too long to get back just a few records.

**Explain result:**

```
#   id  select_type  table           partitions     type        possible_keys                       key         key_len    ref                              rows        filtered    Extra
1   1   SIMPLE       market_place    NULL           ref         PRIMARY,COUNTRY                     COUNTRY     10         const                            7143700     100         Using index
2   1   SIMPLE       moderation      NULL           eq_ref      adID,flag_status,composite_index    adID        8          main_database.market_place.ID    1           50          Using where
```

Is there a way to optimize and speed up the query above.? Any help will gladly be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `SELECT  market_place.COUNTRY ,moderation.flag_status` does not make sense -- both of those are constants given in WHERE/ON clauses.  Let's see the _real_ query; it _probably_ has a different `EXPLAIN` plan.

Comment: @RickJames, the selection is generic to simplify  and keep the question brief n relevant

Comment: Why are you `INNER JOIN`ing a subquery instead of directly to the `moderation` table?

Comment: @J.D., point me to where the sub-query is. Also, it would be awesome if you provide a working example based on my schema

Comment: The plan is doing pretty much what you’ve asked it to do with your hinting. The problem is that the data distribution in your tables means that this plan takes a long time to find the 25 rows it wants (from your description it sounds like actually it never finds that many rows so ends up having to loop over every post from that country). Your driving filter is presumably actually the `flag_status=1` filter, looping through these rows in `moderation` to check the `country` could be more efficient. You might need statistics that tell MySQL about the usefulness of this filter

Comment: `INNER JOIN ( SELECT ...) moderation` is where the subquery is. I'd offer up advice but I'm a little confused on what you got going on and these other guys seem to have you covered. The only advice I can generally give is maybe try getting rid of the subquery and directly `INNER JOIN` to the table. It probably won't solve your problem, but doing unnecessary things like that has hurt people in the past, performance-wise.

Comment: @J.D. - Thank you for the tip. Am considering merging the tables into one super table as a temporary fix instead of joining

Answer (score 0):

Countries have standard 2-letter abbreviations.  Use them rather than having to look them up.  This would eliminate the JOIN and probably make the query faster.

If you need other columns from either table, so state!!

This *might* help:

```
INDEX(flag_status,  adID)
```

The convention for `ON` versus `WHERE` is to put the conditions that define the relationship in `ON`; and put "filtering" clauses in `WHERE`.  (For `INNER JOIN`, they are equivalent, but it helps humans to make the distinction.)

Use `COUNTRY` as the `PRIMARY KEY`, not the artificial `BIGINT` that is 4 times as large!

Comment: That would seem so obvious right.? Well, again the schema you're seeing is really simplified and the moderation table holds more data than just the country code

Comment: I have also tried what you're suggesting. It ain't working. It only works if I remove one condition from the on clause; but then, this defeats the purpose entirely

Comment: You can use the schema I provided and generate 15m generic records and see what I mean.

Comment: @Dennisrec - Notice how the `EXPLAIN` says "Using index".  This means that the index is "covering".  Does it say that for the 'real' query against the 'real' schema?  If not, then you have over-simplified things.  It is usually OK to leave things out of the list of things being `SELECTed`, but the rest of the query should be left intact.

Comment: I've left nothing out. The result of the explain is exactly what I've posted there. It's also worth mentioning that the query is way faster when records are under 100,000 but since I generated 15million generic records, it's incredibly slow even if it show as using indexes

Comment: I also tried adding a limit inside the inner join select stmt but this returns partial results as some records are at the very end of the table

Comment: Well, I stick by getting rid `marketPlace` in this query -- which seems to be used only for lookup for GB via an ID.